I'm getting CS0766 error on Mapperly, but I think I've done well according to getting started guide
I'm trying Mapperly following the Getting Started guide, but with this part:
[Mapper]
public partial class ClientesMapper
{

    public partial DatosCliente ToDatosClientes(CLIENTES origen);

}

I get the CS0766 error: partial methods must return void.
I've been looking the guide and the FAQ but I don't see anything about it. I've tried with 4.7.2 and 4.8.1 (the last one) versions of .NET Framework
How can I solve this?
Thank's

there's a compiler-error that tells you pretty exactly what you should do: "Partial method must have an implementation, because it has an accessibility modifier". We can't know what that method should do, but it should do anything. Currently it's just there will be something.

Since Mapperly is a .NET source generator for generating object mappings, you need to build the code to generate something.
The text editor shows it as an error when you write it

Then Build the project (or try rebuilding the solution)

